# document not getting deleted in mongo using jwt token

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

Task of code : Is to delete document from DB using JWT token
error : sending 500 internal error

code of Auth.js

```
const auth=async(req,res,next)=>{
try{
    const token=req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ','');
    const decoded=jwt.verify(token,'helloworld');
    const user=await User.findOne({_id:decoded._id,'tokens.token':token});
    if(!user){
        throw new Error();
    }
    // console.log(token);
    req.token=token;
    req.user=user;
    next();
}
catch(err){
    // console.log(token);
    res.status(401).send({error:"please authenticate"});
}
}
module.exports=auth;
```

Code To delete document (API endpoint)

```
router.delete('/users/me',auth,async(req,res)=>{
try{
    await req.user.remove();
    res.status(201).send(req.user);
}
catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(req.user);
    res.status(500).send();
}
```

})

The Problem is even if I am sending incorrect JWT token it should give me `{error : please authenticate}` but I am not getting this error too instead I am getting 500 internal error and same error when sending correct JWT .
Even I am printing error in console ,its not showing error in console

Comment: In the console log do _console.log(err.message)_ so you can see the exact error message.

Comment: Used console.log(err.message) not showing message

Comment: User.findOne({_id:decoded._id,'tokens.token':token})*.exec()*; I would add exec() at the end to retrieve the user object

Answer (score 0):

In your API endpoint, you have to call your collection name then you need to remove with query/params id.

If you are using mongoose Like this and send id from frontend as query/params,

```js
Model.remove({ _id: req.body.id }, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    message.type = 'notification!';
  } else {
    message.type = 'error';
  }
});
```

or

```js
router.delete('/users/me/:id', auth, async(req,res) => {
  try {
    await Model.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id})
    res.status(201).send(req.user);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

I hope if you follow this way you can solve this problem.

This is the wrong way to remove `await req.user.remove();` Because, when code executes it will don't know which collection of data needs to remove.

Comment: Actually I am watching a tutorial and the guy did the same code which i wrote but he is not getting error and worked correctly

Comment: When was the video published that you are watching? Whatever try this or follow mongoose documentation. Try to read and research you will get the perfect answer I hope.